# Proving that $Ra$ is a submodule of A.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Here is the question:

[image]

My answer is as follows:

To show that $Ra$ is a  submodule I will use the submodule criterion, which is given in the following picture:

[image]

First, $Ra$ is a subset of A because it is all the elements of the ring $R$ multiplied by the element a of A, and since A is an $R$-module so it is closed under the ring action.

Second, $Ra \neq \phi$ because R is a ring so it contains 0 the additive zero element so $0a = 0 \in Ra$.

Third,

I want to show that : $\forall x,y \in Ra$ & $\forall a_{1} \in A$, we have $(x + a_{1}y) \in Ra.$(I am not sure from my next steps)

since A is an $R-module$ so it is closed under multiplication so $ay \in A$ $\forall a \in A,  \forall y \in Ra$.(I am not sure from this because I am not sure from commutativity of multiplication in Ra, so it is better for me to prove $ya \in Ra$ but by proving this I will not use exactly the submodule criterion, so could anyone help me please? )

Then I want to use that $Ra$ is closed under addition, but I am not sure why this is true, could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: You must show that if $x,y \in Ra$ then $x + ry \in Ra$ for any $r \in R$. Note that the hypothesis means that $x = r'a$, $y = r''a$ for some $r',r'' \in R$. Can you see why, then, $$x + ry = r'a + r(r''a) \in Ra$$ to finish the proof?

Comment: So, all my answer is right except "third", right?

Comment: I can see now that each of the 2 terms beside the + sign belongs to Ra, but I can not see why their sum belongs to Ra ...... could you tell me why please?

Comment: @Intuition Apply distributivity to get $r'a + rr''a = (r' + rr'')a$.